# What is the proper way to consume pieces of a slice in a loop when the piece size can change each iteration?

Tags: rust

I need to process a slice of bytes into fixed chunks, but the chunk pattern is only known at runtime:

```
pub fn process(mut message: &[u8], pattern: &[Pattern]) {
    for element in pattern: {
        match element {
            (...) => {
                let (chunk, message2) = message.split_at(element.size);
                /* process chunk */
                message = message2;
            },
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

It feels awkward to have to use this `message2`. But if I do

```
let (chunk, message) = message.split_at(element.size);
```

Then it does not work, I assume because this actually creates a new `messages` binding that goes out of scope between loop iterations.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your reasoning that `let (chunk, message) = message.split_at(element.size);` creates a new binding `message` within that scope and does not update the outer `message` value.

What you are looking for is a 'destructuring assignment' of the tuple. This would allow tuple elements to be assigned to existing variable bindings instead of creating new bindings, something like:

```
let chunk;
(chunk, message) = message.split_at(element.size);
```

Unfortunately this is currently not possible in Rust. You can see [a pre-RFC which proposes to add destructuring assignment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/372) to the Rust language.

I believe what you currently have is a perfectly fine solution, perhaps rename `message2` to something like `rest_of_message` or `remaining_message`.

Comment: Oh well. I'll keep an eye on this RFC. Thanks !